# Empty (white space) on HTC Android (4.0.3) at the top of browser window

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, css

We are building a web app for mobile devices.

The app has a fixed (position:absolute, top:0px) top header, and a scrollable content in the rest of the page. The app also has a text area in it.

When we focus on the text area, the keyboard appears (as expected) and the window scrolls up (to make way for the keyboard). The problem is that the top header disapears and is replaced by a white horizontal space (pretty much equivalent to the size of the address bar). I've verified that the header is not moved/scrolled up, but has definitely been masked/replaced by the white space.

Is there a way to get rid of this problem?

Note: This happens only with HTC and the Android (4.0.3) Default Browser on it.

Thanks.
Saket

Comment: did you try to set the top padding and top margin to 0?

Comment: There is no top padding or margin applied. So I'm hoping it'd be 0 anyways.

Comment: @Saket That's a big assumption.  `<h>` is a `<div>` tag where browsers give it default styling.  `<ul>` is a tag that generally gets default margins.  Why would you trust any tag to a default setting?  Test it with specified settings of 0.  Every browser follows (or doesn't follow) the W3C standards differently.

Comment: setting the margin/padding to 0 didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In your page CSS, try to add

```
body{
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
}
```

Comment: Let me try and get back on this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't since its confidential. Is there any other way of troubleshooting?

Comment: i think no there's no other way, this could be an endless trial and error. you can remove or replace those confidential data anyway?

Comment: WebView margin?? - Its a pure web app...that renders on a browser.